# Symfony2 / Form - Change GET Method generated URL

Tags: forms, symfony, routes

I have form with GET method, and action where I have 3 optional parameters.
But if I submit form, form generate url like this: "example.com/keyword=test?category=test1?country=test2"

But my route looks like "example.com/{keyword}/{category}/{country}"

How can I solve this issue?

I tried this:

```
if($form->isValid()){
   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route', array('keyword' => $form['keyword']->getData(), ... )));
}
```

But I can't because I render my form in ::base.html.twig, and redirection doesn't work ...

**searchFormAction:**

```
public function searchFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType(),null, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('web_portal_search')));
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
//            return $this->redirectToRoute('web_portal_search',
//                array(
//                    'keyword' => $form['keyword']->getData(),
//                    'category' => $form['category']->getData(),
////                    'country' => $form['country']->getData()
//                    ));
        }
        return $this->render('WebPortalBundle:Default/Search:searchForm.html.twig', array('searchForm' => $form->createView()), $this->get('WebPortalBundle')->cache($request));
    }
```

**searchAction:**

```
public function searchAction($keyword = null, $category = null, $country = null, Request $request){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $search = $em->getRepository('DbBundle:Ads')->search($keyword, $category, $country);

        return $this->render('WebPortalBundle:Default/Search:search.html.twig', array('search' $search));
    }
```

**Route:**

```
web_portal_search:
    path:     /{keyword}/{category}/{country}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Search:search, keyword: null, category: null, country: null, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
        page: \d+
```

**::base.html.twig:**

```
...
{{ render(controller('WebPortalBundle:Search:searchForm')) }}
...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve the problem, but you don't need to pass the Request parameter in searchAction. You can access the request with $this->getRequest() anyway.

Besides, your route has a "page" parameter which is not set in your searchAction. I think this function should be written like this :

```
public function searchAction($keyword = null, $category = null, $country = null, $page = 1){
    // do your stuff here
}
```

I can't test this right now but let me know if this solves your problem...

Comment: I tried, and now it works. Might issue was in $page = 1. Thanks 
PS: I can use $this->getRequest()  but it's deprecated.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, indeed, getRequest is deprecated. Sorry for that !